# Finding out clicked Line2d from multiple lines

Tags: java, swing, line, paint, paintcomponent

I have drawn multiple tilted Line2Ds on screen using paint(),I need to find out the one clicked by the user.I am using  Rectangle2D rect = line.getBounds2D(); to find the clicked line2D.This works most of the times except when one line is just below the other.During such a time,the rectangle bounds of the upper line is such that they it consists of the region which also includes lower line.Hence,I get incorrect clicked line duing such times.Any solution or alternate approach?

Answer (score 0):

Find lesser distance from click point to any of that bounds-overlapping lines. Thats must be something related with line-equation and perpendicular line, which goes from click point to line of interest.

Detailed info you can find (and should from the start) on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line).